# Parse.comのPFRelationを利用した値の保存について（swift使用）

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

現在Parse.comのPFRelationを利用して物とその所有者の関係性を保存したいと考えています。
プログラムは以下の通りです。

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    var relation = user.relationForKey("ownership")
    var object = PFObject(className: "Goods")
    object["name"] = "Book"
    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded :Bool!, error :NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            relation.addObject(object)
            user.saveInBackground()
        }
    }
```

エラー等は出ませんが、ブラウザで確認するとParseのデータベースにうまく保存されていません。ドキュメント等を見ても解決法がわからなかったためこちらで質問させていただきました。
ご教授のほどよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var relation = user.relationForKey("ownership")
var object = PFObject(className: "Goods")
object["name"] = "Book"
object["user"] = user
object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded :Bool!, error :NSError!) -> Void in
    if (error == nil){

    }
}
```

のようにすればUserと結びつけられますがどうでしょうか。

Comment: 遅くなりました！ありがとうございます。